# Selenium server hangs "could n't create firefox profile"

Tags: firefox, testing, selenium

I am trying to run selenium test suite from terminal using following command:

```
java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar -timeout 60 -htmlSuite "   firefox /usr/lib/firefox/firefox" "http://url " "/test-     case/new/test_suite.html" "/test-case/selenium.html"
```

running the above command in terminal outputs following->

```
  20:08:59.134 INFO - Launching a standalone server
  20:08:59.175 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.45-b02 
  20:08:59.176 INFO - OS: Linux 3.13.0-52-generic amd64
  20:08:59.186 INFO - v2.45.0, with Core v2.45.0. Built from revision 5017cb8
  20:08:59.247 INFO - Default driver org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match with current platform: LINUX
  20:08:59.300 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
  20:08:59.301 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
  20:08:59.303 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
  20:08:59.328 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@256216b3
  20:08:59.328 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
  20:08:59.329 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
  20:08:59.329 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
  20:08:59.332 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
  20:08:59.332 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@133314b
  jar:file:/var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar!/customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME
  20:08:59.465 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
  <-----stuck here--->
```

After searching the web, I found a lot of solutions (answered before 2013). The summary of those solutions are incompatibility between selenium server and Firefox version. I tried most the solutions but none of them worked.

I am using ubuntu 14.04(docker-image). Firefox is running perfectly under xvfb. .py test suites are also running perfectly using selenium python module. The problem occurs only when the test suites are invoked from terminal.

Selenium server version: 2.45.0
Firefox version: 38.0

Need solution badly.

Comment: Please run `strace java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar -timeout 60 …` and add the last ~20 lines to your post.

Comment: I have installed "strace" using apt-get install then running your given command gives following output. root@309fd63c73d5:/test-case# strace java -jar /var/lib/selenium  /selenium-server.jar -timeout 60
      strace: test_ptrace_setoptions_for_all: PTRACE_TRACEME doesn't work: Permission denied
     strace: test_ptrace_setoptions_for_all: unexpected exit status 1

Comment: Uh, can you please put your *entire* java command line after the strace call? And please post the last 20 lines in some paste bin, so they can be read line by line.

Comment: Here is the strace: http://pastebin.com/UpgiS8hF. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, that's not too helpful. :( Can you set the log level of Selenium to debug and try again?